# Using MySQL last insert id for the same user

Tags: php, mysql, insert, race-condition

I'm using the mysql_insert_id within my code to get an auto increment.

I have read around and it looks like there is no race condition regarding this for different user connections, but what about the same user?  Will I be likely to run into race condition problems when connecting to the database using the same username/user but still from different connection sessions?

My application is PHP.  When a user submits a web request my PHP executes code and for that particular request/connection session I keep a persistent SQL connection open in to MySQL for the length of that request.  Will this cause me any race condition problems?

Answer (score 0):

None for any practical purpose, If you execute the last_id request right after executing your insert then there is practically not enough time for another insert to spoil that. Theoretically might be 
possible

According to [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

> Note:
>
> Because mysql_insert_id() acts on the last performed query, be sure to
>   call mysql_insert_id() immediately after the query that generates the
>   value.

Just in case you want to double check you can use this function to confirm your previous query

[mysql_info](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-info.php)

Comment: And Btw, its not good to continue using mysql_* functions for new code

Answer (score 0):

The use of persistent connections doesn't mean that every request will use the same connection. It means that each apache thread will have its own connection that is shared between all requests executing on that thread.

The requests will run serially (one after another) which means that the same persistent connection will not be used by two threads running at the same time.

Because of this, your `last_insert_id` value will be safe, but be sure that you check the result of your inserts before using it, because it *will* return the last_insert_id of the last successful INSERT, even if it wasn't the last executed INSERT.